# CryptoJS WordArray and Drive API PATCH update in Javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, google-chrome-extension, cryptojs

I am writing Chrome extension which requires Drive API and [CryptoJS](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js). It can already get byte in arrayBuffer() form, decrypt and read json:

```
fetch(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' + fileId + '?alt=media',
        {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
            'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }
).then(response => response.arrayBuffer()
).then(function(respRaw) {
    let respWordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(respRaw);
    let dcWordArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
        {
            ciphertext: respWordArray
        }, 
        key,
        {   // "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"
            iv: iv,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        }
    );
    let resptext = dcWordArray.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    let respJson = JSON.parse(resptext);
}
```

Now, I wanna reverse every and update the encrypted content back to Google Drive:

```
let newtext = JSON.stringify(respJson);
let newWordArray = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(newtext);
let ecWordArray = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt( // RangeError: Invalid array length
    {
        ciphertext: newWordArray
    }, 
    key,
    {   // "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    }
);

//let dcBase64String = ecWordArray.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
let uint8array     = convertWordArrayToUint8Array(ecWordArray);
let binaryString   = convertUint8ArrayToBinaryString(uint8array);

fetch(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/' + fileId,
    {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
            'Accept': 'text/plain',
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        },
        body: binaryString
    }
).then(response => response.text()
).then(function(data) {
    console.log('data:' + data);
    }
);
```

Sadly, an error occurred during CryptoJS.AES.encrypt():

```
RangeError: Invalid array length
at WordArray.init.clamp (crypto-js.js:272)
at WordArray.init.concat (crypto-js.js:237)
at Object.pad (crypto-js.js:3666)
at Object._doFinalize (crypto-js.js:3743)
at Object.finalize (crypto-js.js:3414)
at Object.encrypt (crypto-js.js:3926)
at Object.encrypt (crypto-js.js:3452)
at downup.js:2894
```

so I have no idea if the rest of type conversion are correct.
As I can see, newWordArray is same as dcWordArray.  Please clear up my mind that:

- Are newWordArray & dcWordArray really WordArray? how to verify?
- For PATCH update, how to send the WordArray as ArrayBuffer?
- solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thing became obvious once I knew how to check the data type + values. For example, some parameter called **ecResult**:

```
console.log(ecResult);
> {$super: {…}, words: Array(28), sigBytes: 112, init: ƒ}
```

CryptoJS.AES.encrypt was not just holding WordArray. So i'd rename it and convert it to ArrayBuffer:

```
let ecResult = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
    newWordArray,
    key,
    {   // "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding"
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        }
);
let ecWordArray = ecResult.ciphertext; // this is WordArray
let ecArrayBuf = CryptJsWordArrayToUint8Array( // github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/274
    ecWordArray
).buffer; // now we have ArrayBuffer
```

Finally, update the file with ArrayBuffer via Drive API:

```
fetch(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/' + fileId,
    {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
            'Accept': 'text/plain',
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            },
        body: ecArrayBuf                                
        }
).then(response => response.text()
).then(function(data) {
    console.log('data:' + data);
);
```